# call method when select option from dopdown vue

Tags: vue-component

I have multiselect in vue component. when I select an item from that dropdown it should execute a method. but that method is calling in page load. but I want to call that method when I select an item from dropdown only. how to get it done.

### multiselect in vue component

```
    <multiselect v-model="value" placeholder="Search Categories" @input="updateSelected" :allow-empty="false"
                           :options="categories" :taggable="true" :custom-label='categoriesWithTitle' track-by='id'
                           :show-labels="false">
   </multiselect>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using [`vue-multiselect`](https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect) ?
If it's the case, there is a `@select` event -> `Emitted after selecting an option`, this one should do the trick.

Here, your code is triggered on page load because you are probably having some dynamic value on your `value` prop (@input >> "Emitted after this.value changes").

https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-events

Comment: @select also not calling to method

Comment: Should work properly as shown in the official example: https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-action-dispatcher Do you have a link that can show more context about your issue ? It's maybe coming from elsewhere here. Are you sure your method is not called ? Try a `console.log` inside of it to be sure. :D

Comment: finally it works. I forgot to put selected value in method call.that the case it didn't work. thanks a lot @kissu

Comment: Glad it's now working, thanks for the accepted answer. :D